# Suspense not working with layouts in vue 3

Tags: vue.js, layout, vuejs3, vue-router

I have a view router with meta, where the layouts of each page are indicated. The problem is that suspense is triggered only once after a reboot. When switching to the same layout via router-link, it does not cause suspense. If you go through different layouts suspense works as it should. I can't figure out what the problem might be.

App.vue:

```
<script setup>
import {RouterView, useRoute, useRouter} from 'vue-router';
import {computed} from "vue";
import NotifiactionBlock from "./views/./components/blocks/NotifiactionBlock.vue";
import LoadSpinner from "./views/components/elements/spinners/LoadSpinner.vue";

const router = useRouter();
const route = useRoute();

const layout = computed(() => {
    const {meta} = useRoute();
    return meta.layout ?? 'default-layout';
});

</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <component :is="layout">
            <RouterView v-slot="{ Component }">
                <template v-if="Component">
                    <Transition name="page" mode="out-in">
                        <Suspense>
                            <component :is="Component"></component>
                            <template #fallback>
                                <load-spinner></load-spinner>
                            </template>
                        </Suspense>
                    </Transition>
                </template>
            </RouterView>
        </component>

        <NotifiactionBlock></NotifiactionBlock>
    </div>

</template>
```

one of the pages (HomeView):

```
<template>
    <div class="images-list">
        <div class="header-block">
            <h2>Recommended images for you</h2>
        </div>
        <images-list :images="store.images"></images-list>
    </div>
</template>

<script async setup>
import ImagesList from "../components/blocks/ImagesList.vue";
import {useImageStore} from "../../stores/image";
import LoadSpinner from "../components/elements/spinners/LoadSpinner.vue";

const store = useImageStore();
await store.setRecommendedImages();
</script>
```

async method in HomeView from pinia:

```
async function setRecommendedImages() {
        const response = await requestRecommendedImages();
        images.value = response.data.data;
    }
```

vue router:

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  linkActiveClass: 'active',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: HomeView,
      meta: {
        layout: MainLayout,
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/images/:id',
      name: 'image',
      component: ImageView,
    },
    {
      path: '/register',
      name: 'register',
      component: RegisterView,
      meta: {
        layout: AuthLayout,
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: LoginView,
      meta: {
        layout: AuthLayout,
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/liked',
      name: 'liked',
      component: LikedView,
      meta: {
        layout: MainLayout,
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/profile',
      name: 'profile',
      component: ProfileView,
      meta: {
        layout: DefaultLayout,
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/users/:id',
      name: 'users',
      component: UserView,
      meta: {
        layout: MainLayout,
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/top',
      name: 'top',
      component: TopView,
      meta: {
        layout: MainLayout,
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to add `timeout` on `Suspense` ?

```html
<RouterView v-slot="{ Component }">
  <Suspense>
    <component :is="layout">
      <Suspense timeout="0">
        <template #default>
          <component :is="Component" />
        </template>
        <template #fallback>
           <load-spinner></load-spinner>
        </template>
      </Suspense>
    </component>
  </Suspense>
</RouterView>
```